# Get only one item from the array response in the Postman body using json

Tags: json, postman

I am very new to Postman and have a method in my API taking in 2 params: AccountNumber and GroupId to check if there's a customer Id associated with the AccountNumber. When I run the Post request, if it returns 2 or more customerIds, I'm supposed to return the response to the user to pick which customerId to use. How do I do that?
Right now, in the body of the request, I have:

```
{
    "AccountNumber":"0001",
    "GroupId": "1"
}
```

The output is an array of customerId. How do I test with only one customerId picked from the POST response?

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely to be a Postman issue.

You are consuming the API through Postman. You are not able to control the output of the API itself from Postman.

What you can do, though, is write a test case for the current request. There is a 'Tests' tab, where the 'Params' tab is. At the right, there are snippets on how to create the test with response body. Let me give you a simple test case to get the first element:

Let's say I have the following response body

```
[
  {
    "name": "Blue",
    "id": "5f1830d217afbb52acac9868"
  },
  {
    "name": "Orange",
    "id": "5f1e7afeb334ae70b4f05d1d"
  },
  {
    "name": "Red",
    "id": "5f1e7b10b334ae70b4f05d1e"
  },
  {
    "name": "Green",
    "id": "5f1e7b10b334ae70b4f05d1f"
  },
  {
    "name": "Yellow",
    "id": "5f1e7b10b334ae70b4f05d20"
  }
]
```

The test case would look like this:

```
pm.test("Example Test", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonData[0]).to.eql({
            name: "Blue", 
            id: "5f1830d217afbb52acac9868"
    });
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, it's still displaying all customers

Comment: Could you provide the javascript of the test, please?